# How do I fix the the "no sollution" in IBM Cplex?

Tags: cplex

I am working on a model for a multi-echelon supply chain network. The system focuses on supply chain of manufacturing plants, warehouses, distribution centers, and customer zones. The manufacturing sites are multipurpose production plants. After being produced, the products are maintained at warehouses and distribution centers. Each warehouse may be supplied material from more than one manufacturing site. Similarly, a distribution center can be supplied from more than one warehouse. At the end of the supply chain, customers place their orders at distribution centers and the distribution centers distribute finished products to customers.

The goal is to determine the number, location, and capacity of centers to be set up, the transportation links that need to be established in the network, and the flows and production rates of materials, with the objective to minimize total cost while still meeting some specified requirements, or constraints.

This is my code and data. I tried this but it shows no solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
using CP;


{string} Prod = ...;
{string} Plant = ...;
{string} Family = ...;
{string} Customer = ...;
{string} Resource = ...;

int NBRange = ...;
range Range1=0..NBRange;

int NbWarehouses = ...;
range WH = 1..NbWarehouses;

int NbDists = ...;
range DI = 1.. NbDists;



tuple ProductFamily{
 string Family;
}

ProductFamily Pro[Prod]= ...;

float ManuCostW[WH] = ...;
float ManuCostD[DI] = ...;
float ProductCost[Prod][Plant] = ...;
float CostHandlW[Prod][WH] = ...;
float CostHandlD[Prod][DI] = ...; 
float TransCostP[Family][Plant][WH] = ...;
float TransCostW[Family][WH][DI] = ...;
float TransCostD[Family][DI][Customer] = ...;

float MaxRateFlowP[Prod][Plant][WH];
float MaxRateFlowW[Prod][WH][DI];
float MaxRateFlowD[Prod][DI][Customer];

float MinRateFlowW[WH][DI] = ...;
float MinRateFlowD[DI][Customer] = ...;
float Demand[Prod][Customer] = ...;
float Coef[Prod][Plant][Resource] = ...;
float MinCapW[WH] = ...;
float MaxCapW[WH] = ...;
float MinCapD[DI] = ...;
float MaxCapD[DI] = ...;
float MinProdRate[Prod][Plant] = ...;
float MaxProdRate[Prod][Plant] = ...;
float CoefcapW[Prod][WH]= ...;
float CoefcapD[Prod][DI]=...;

dvar int+ ProdRate[Prod][Plant];
dvar int+ RateFlowP[Prod][Plant][WH];
dvar int+ RateFlowW[Prod][WH][DI];
dvar int+ RateFlowD[Prod][DI][Customer];
 dvar int CapW[WH];
 dvar int CapD[DI];

float RateOfAvail[Resource][Plant]= ...;

dvar int TransCostPreal[Family][Plant][WH] ;
dvar int TransCostWreal[Family][WH][DI] ;
dvar int TransCostDreal[Family][DI][Customer] ;
dvar int Q[Family][Plant][WH][1..NBRange];
dvar int Qq[Family][WH][DI][1..NBRange];
dvar int Qqq[Family][DI][Customer][1..NBRange];

float Flow[1..NBRange]=...;
float CoefofFlow[1..NBRange]=...;

dvar boolean OpenW[WH];
dvar boolean OpenD[DI];
dvar boolean AssignD[WH][DI];
dvar boolean AssignC[DI][Customer];

dvar boolean Z[Family][Plant][WH][1..NBRange];
dvar boolean Zz[Family][WH][DI][1..NBRange];
dvar boolean Zzz[Family][DI][Customer][1..NBRange];

minimize 
 sum(m in WH)
   (ManuCostW[m]*OpenW[m])+
 sum(k in DI)
   (ManuCostD[k]*OpenD[k])+  
 sum(i in Prod,j in Plant)
   (ProductCost[i][j]*ProdRate[i][j])+
 sum(i in Prod, m in WH)
    (CostHandlW[i][m]*
    sum(j in Plant)
      (RateFlowP[i][j][m])) +
 sum(i in Prod, k in DI)
    (CostHandlD[i][k]*
    sum(m in WH)
      (RateFlowW[i][m][k])) + 
 sum(f in Family,j in Plant,m in WH)
       (TransCostPreal[f][j][m]) +
 sum(f in Family, m in WH, k in DI)
       (TransCostWreal[f][m][k]) +   
 sum(f in Family, k in DI, l in Customer)
       (TransCostDreal[f][k][l]);

subject to {
//Network
forall (m in WH, k in DI)
   AssignD[m][k]<=OpenW[m];
forall (k in DI, m in WH)
  AssignD[m][k]<=OpenD[k];   
forall (k in DI, l in Customer)
  AssignC[k][l]<=OpenD[k];  
   
//maximum rate of flow constraints   
forall (i in Prod, j in Plant, m in WH)
  MaxRateFlowP[i][j][m]== minl(MaxProdRate[i][j],sum(k in DI)(MaxRateFlowW[i][m][k])); 
forall (i in Prod, m in WH, k in DI) 
  MaxRateFlowW[i][m][k]== minl(sum(j in Plant)(MaxRateFlowP[i][j][m]),sum(l in Customer)(MaxRateFlowD[i][k][l]));
forall (i in Prod, k in DI, l in Customer)
  MaxRateFlowD[i][k][l]== minl (sum(m in WH )(MaxRateFlowW[i][m][k]),Demand[i][l])   ;
//Transporatation constraint
forall (f in Family, j in Plant, m in WH)
  sum(r in 1..NBRange)(Z[f][j][m][r])==1;
forall (f in Family, j in Plant, m in WH, r in 1..NBRange: (r-1)in 1..NBRange)
  (Flow[r-1]*Z[f][j][m][r])<= (Q[f][j][m][r]);
forall (f in Family, j in Plant, m in WH, r in 1..NBRange)  
   Q[f][j][m][r]<=Flow[r]*Z[f][j][m][r];
forall (f in Family, j in Plant, m in WH)
  sum (i in Prod)(RateFlowP[i][j][m])==sum(r in 1..NBRange)(Q[f][j][m][r])  ;
forall (f in Family, j in Plant, m in WH)
   TransCostPreal[f][j][m]==sum (r in 1..NBRange: (r-1)in 1..NBRange)((TransCostP[f][j][m]*CoefofFlow[r-1]*Z[f][j][m][r]) + (Q[f][j][m][r]-Flow[r-1]*Z[f][j][m][r])*((TransCostP[f][j][m]*CoefofFlow[r]-TransCostP[f][j][m]*CoefofFlow[r-1])/(Q[f][j][m][r]-Q[f][j][m][r-1]))); 

forall (f in Family, k in DI , m in WH)
  sum(r in 1..NBRange)(Zz[f][m][k][r])==1;
forall (f in Family, k in DI , m in WH, r in 1..NBRange: (r-1)in 1..NBRange)
  Flow[r-1]*Zz[f][m][k][r]<= Qq[f][m][k][r];
forall (f in Family, k in DI, m in WH, r in 1..NBRange)  
  Qq[f][m][k][r]<=Flow[r]*Zz[f][m][k][r];
forall (f in Family, k in DI, m in WH)
  sum (i in Prod)(RateFlowW[i][m][k])==sum(r in 1..NBRange)(Qq[f][m][k][r])  ;
forall (f in Family, k in DI, m in WH)
   TransCostWreal[f][m][k]== sum (r in 1..NBRange: (r-1)in 1..NBRange)(TransCostW[f][m][k]*CoefofFlow[r-1]*Zz[f][m][k][r] 
   + (Qq[f][m][k][r]-Flow[r-1]*Zz[f][m][k][r])*
   ((TransCostW[f][m][k]*CoefofFlow[r]-TransCostW[f][m][k]*CoefofFlow[r-1])/(Qq[f][m][k][r]-Qq[f][m][k][r-1])));  
   
forall (f in Family, k in DI , l in Customer)
  sum(r in 1..NBRange)(Zzz[f][k][l][r])==1;
forall (f in Family, k in DI , l in Customer, r in 1..NBRange: (r-1)in 1..NBRange)
  Flow[r-1]*Zzz[f][k][l][r]<= Qqq[f][k][l][r];
forall (f in Family, k in DI, l in Customer, r in 1..NBRange)  
   Qqq[f][k][l][r]<=Flow[r]*Zzz[f][k][l][r];
forall (f in Family, k in DI, l in Customer)
  sum (i in Prod)(RateFlowD[i][k][l])==sum(r in 1..NBRange)(Qqq[f][k][l][r])  ;
forall (f in Family, k in DI, l in Customer)
   TransCostDreal[f][k][l]== sum (r in 1..NBRange: (r-1)in 1..NBRange)(TransCostD[f][k][l]*CoefofFlow[r-1]*Zzz[f][k][l][r]  + (Qqq[f][k][l][r]-Flow[r-1]*Zzz[f][k][l][r])*((TransCostD[f][k][l]*CoefofFlow[r]-TransCostD[f][k][l]*CoefofFlow[r-1])/(Qqq[f][k][l][r]-Qqq[f][k][l][r-1])));     
 //Logical flow 
forall (i in Prod, j in Plant, m in WH)
  RateFlowP[i][j][m]<= (MaxRateFlowP[i][j][m]*OpenW[m]);
forall (i in Prod, m in WH, k in DI)
  RateFlowW[i][m][k]<= (MaxRateFlowW[i][m][k]*AssignD[m][k]);  
forall (i in Prod, k in DI, l in Customer)
   RateFlowD[i][k][l]<= (MaxRateFlowD[i][k][l]*AssignC[k][l]);     
forall (m in WH, k in DI)
   sum(i in Prod)(RateFlowW[i][m][k])>= (MinRateFlowW[m][k]*AssignD[m][k]);  
forall (k in DI, l in Customer)
   sum(i in Prod)(RateFlowD[i][k][l])>= (MinRateFlowD[k][l]*AssignC[k][l]);     
 
//Material Bls
forall (i in Prod, j in Plant)    
   ProdRate[i][j]== sum (m in WH)(RateFlowP[i][j][m]);
forall (i in Prod, m in WH)    
    sum (j in Plant)(RateFlowP[i][j][m])==sum (k in DI)(RateFlowW[i][m][k]);  
forall (i in Prod, k in DI)    
    sum (m in WH)(RateFlowW[i][m][k])==sum (l in Customer)(RateFlowD[i][k][l]); 
forall (i in Prod, l in Customer)      
   sum (k in DI)(RateFlowD[i][k][l])==  Demand[i][l];

//Production Resource     
 forall (i in Prod, j in Plant)
    MinProdRate[i][j]<= ProdRate[i][j]<=MaxProdRate[i][j];
forall (j in Plant, e in Resource)
     sum (i in Prod)(ProdRate[i][j]*Coef[i][j][e])<=  RateOfAvail[e][j];      
 
 //Capacity
forall (m in WH)
   CapW[m]>= MinCapW[m]*OpenW[m];
 forall (m in WH)    
   CapW[m]<= MaxCapW[m]*OpenW[m]; 
 forall (k in DI)    
   CapD[k]<= MaxCapD[k]*OpenD[k];
 forall (k in DI)
    CapD[k]>= MinCapD[k]*OpenD[k]; 
 forall (m in WH)
    CapW[m]>= sum(i in Prod, k in DI)(CoefcapW[i][m]*RateFlowW[i][m][k]) ;
 forall (k in DI)
    CapD[k]>= sum(i in Prod, l in Customer)(CoefcapD[i][k]*RateFlowD[i][k][l]) ;              
}     
execute DISPLAY_RESULTS{
  writeln("OpenW=",OpenW);
  writeln("OpenD=",OpenD);
  writeln("AssignD=",AssignD);
  writeln("AssignC=",AssignC);
}
Data (Case Study 1: Deterministic Product Demands)
NbWarehouses = 6;
NbDists =15;

NBRange = 4;


Prod ={"p1","p2","p3","p4","p5","p6","p7","p8","p9","p10","p11","p12","p13","p14"};
Plant ={"PL1","PL2","PL3"};
Customer ={"c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8","c9","c10","c11","c12","c13","c14","c15","c16","c17","c18"};
Resource ={"E1","E2","E3","E4","E5","E6"};
Family ={"F1","F2","F3"};


Flow=[ 40 100 1000 5000];
CoefofFlow= [ 1 0.95 0.89 0.8];

//Family
Pro =#[
p1:<F1>
p2:<F1>
p3:<F1>
p4:<F1>
p5:<F1>
p6:<F1>
p10:<F1>
p11:<F3>
p12:<F3>
p13:<F3>
p14:<F3>
p7:<F2>
p8:<F2>
p9:<F2>]#;
//Maximum and Minimum Production Capacity of Each Plant j for Each Product i
MaxProdRate=
[[ 158    0 972]
 [2268 1411 778]
 [1701 1058 607]
 [1512 1328 540]
 [   0  996   0]
 [ 812  664 416]
 [ 642  664 416]
 [ 482    0 312]
 [ 320    0 208]
 [ 504    0   0]
 [   0  530 403]
 [ 661  469   0]
 [ 441  330 270]
 [ 221    0   0]];
MinProdRate= 
[[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]];
//Unit Production Costs
ProductCost=
[[ 61.27  59.45  61.44]
 [ 61.27  59.45  61.44]
 [ 61.27  59.45  61.44]
 [ 61.27  59.45  61.44]
 [ 61.27  59.45  61.44]
 [ 61.27  59.45  61.44]
 [256.90 268.50 270.80]
 [256.90 268.50 270.80]
 [256.90 268.50 270.80]
 [ 61.27  59.45  61.44]
 [256.90 268.50 270.80]
 [256.90 268.50 270.80]
 [256.90 268.50 270.80]
 [256.90 268.50 270.80]];

//Fixed Infrastructure and Material Handling Costs for Candidate Warehouses and Distribution Centers
 ManuCostW= [10000 5000 4000 6000 6500 4000];
 ManuCostD= [10000 5000 4000 6000 6500 4000 6000 4000 5000 3000 4500 7000 9000 5500 8500];

//Handling cost 
 CostHandlW=  
 [[4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.06 5.28]];
 CostHandlD=  
 [[4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]
 [4.25 4.55 4.98 4.93 4.85 3.90 4.06 3.08 6.00 4.85 4.12 5.66 5.28 4.95 4.83]];
 
 //Capacities
 MinCapW= [0 0 0 0 0 0];
 MaxCapW= [14000 14000 14000 14000 14000 14000];
 MinCapD= [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
 MaxCapD= [7000 7000 7000 7000 7000 7000 7000 7000 7000 7000 7000 7000 7000 7000 7000];
 //Demand
 Demand=
[[ 18   0   0  15  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  10   0  0   0 15   0   0]
 [  0  99 155 150  0  0 114 50 50  0 50  31  21  0   0  0 103   0]
 [  0  55  50 126 92 50   0  0  0  0  0   0   0  0   0 68   0   0]
 [106 203 266   0  0  0 140 45  0 17 31   0 100 50 150  0 110   0]
 [  0  76   0   0  0  0   0 40  0  0 20   0   0  0   0  0   0   0]
 [252   0  66   0  0 68   0 23  0  0  0 100   0  0   0  0  44 100]
 [  0  30  17   5  0  0   0  0 52  0  0  13  15  0  10  5  12   0]
 [  0   0   0  27  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0   0  7   0 20   0   0]
 [ 43   0   0   0 21 20  34  5  7  5  0   0   0  0   0  0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  38   0  0   0  0   0 266]
 [  0  20   0   0  0  0   0  0  0  0 20   0   0  0  15  0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0  25  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0   0  0   0 20   0   0] 
 [ 70   0  15   0 50 10  68  0  0 16 15   0  50  0   0  0  13   0]
 [ 34   0   0   0  0 10   0  0  0  0 20   0   0  0  10  0   0   0]];
 //Coef[Prod][Plant][Resource] =
 Coef=
 [[[0 0 0 0 0 0.6667]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0.1200 0 0 0]]
 [[0 0.0463 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0.0740 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0.1543 0 0 0 ]]
 [[0 0.0617 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0.1000 0 0 0]
 [0 0.1976 0 0 0 0]]
 [[0 0.0694 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0.0793 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0.2222 0 0 0 0]]
 [[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0.1054 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
 [[0 0 0 0 0.1292 0]
 [0 0.1582 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0.3968 0 0 0]]
 [[0 0 01.634 0 0 0]
 [0 0.1582 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0.3968 0 0 0]]
 [[0 0 0.2178 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0.5291 0 0 0]]
 [[0 0 0.3268 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0.7936 0 0 0]]
 [[0.2381 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
 [[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0.1984 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0.2976 0 0]]
 [[0 0 0 0.2267 0 0]
 [0.2118 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
 [[0 0 0 0.3401 0 0]
 [0.3174 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0.4444 0 0]]
 [[0 0 0 0.6802 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]];
 
 //TransCost[Family][Plant][WH]
 TransCostP=
 [[[ 1.24 58.56 62.30 26.16 17.44 36.13]
[60.82 1.68 70.96 43.93 70.96 55.76]
[76.16 79.21 1.52 54.83 68.54 41.12]]
[[1.35 63.46 67.51 28.35 18.90 39.15]
[82.70 2.29 96.48 59.72 96.48 75.81]
[94.90 98.69 1.89 68.32 85.41 51.24]]
[[1.46 68.88 73.28 30.77 20.51 42.50]
[79.69 2.21 92.97 57.55 92.97 73.05]
[92.82 96.53 1.85 66.83 83.54 50.12]]];

TransCostW=
[[[ 0 74.40 76.13 25.96 69.21 29.41 17.30 117.66 44.99 110.74 76.13 12.11 39.79 64.02 60.56]
[ 58.85 0 62.96 45.16 109.49 69.80 67.06 94.44 90.33 145.08 17.79 60.22 52.01 108.12 72.54]
[72.83 76.14 0 49.66 94.35 99.32 62.90 43.04 79.45 129.12 94.35 62.90 33.10 104.29 28.14]
[28.54 62.78 57.08 0 87.52 58.98 32.34 106.55 62.78 135.09 72.30 22.83 19.02 89.42 49.47]
[16.51 73.58 57.06 25.52 48.05 37.54 0 93.10 25.52 84.09 78.08 7.50 30.03 45.05 42.04]
[69.52 67.78 34.76 17.38 78.21 69.52 34.76 79.95 59.09 121.66 78.21 33.02 0 83.42 27.80]]
[[0 75.28 77.03 26.26 70.02 29.76 17.50 119.04 45.51 112.04 77.03 12.25 40.26 64.77 61.27]
[60.87 0 65.12 46.71 113.25 72.20 69.36 97.68 93.43 150.06 18.40 62.29 53.79 111.84 75.03]
[90.75 94.88 0 61.88 117.57 123.76 78.38 53.63 99.00 160.89 117.57 78.38 41.25 129.95 35.06]
[28.88 63.54 57.77 0 88.58 59.69 32.73 107.83 63.54 136.72 73.17 23.10 19.25 90.50 50.06]
[17.90 79.77 61.86 27.67 52.09 40.70 0 100.93 27.67 91.16 84.65 8.14 32.56 48.84 45.58]
[86.62 84.46 43.31 21.65 97.45 86.62 43.31 99.62 73.63 151.59 97.45 41.14 0 103.95 34.65]]
[[ 0 69.15 70.78 24.14 64.32 27.33 16.08 109.35 41.81 102.92 70.76 11.25 36.98 59.50 56.28]
[69.66 0 74.52 53.46 129.61 82.63 79.38 111.79 106.93 171.74 21.06 71.28 61.56 127.99 85.87]
[92.01 96.19 0 62.73 119.19 125.47 79.46 54.37 100.37 163.11 119.19 79.46 41.82 131.74 35.55]
[26.53 58.37 53.07 0 81.37 54.83 30.07 99.06 58.37 125.59 67.22 21.22 17.69 83.14 45.99]
[20.49 91.29 70.80 31.67 59.62 46.58 0 115.51 31.67 104.33 96.88 9.31 37.26 55.89 52.16]
[87.82 85.63 43.91 21.95 98.80 87.82 43.91 85.70 63.34 130.42 83.84 35.40 0 89.43 35.13]]];

TransCostD=
[[[0 75.61 54.51 12.30 70.34 29.89 17.58 119.57 45.72 112.54 77.37 12.30 40.44 65.06 61.54 45.72 100.23 38.68]
[73.55 0 78.68 73.55 136.84 87.23 83.81 118.02 112.89 181.31 22.23 75.26 64.99 135.12 90.65 34.21 71.84 94.07]
[73.28 76.61 21.65 49.96 94.93 99.93 63.28 43.30 79.94 129.90 94.93 63.28 33.31 104.92 28.31 51.63 21.65 58.29]
[26.58 58.47 53.16 14.17 81.51 54.93 30.12 99.23 58.47 125.81 67.33 21.26 17.72 83.28 46.07 54.93 17.72 40.75]
[77.16 154.33 109.96 84.88 0 90.67 59.80 136.97 27.00 48.23 160.12 69.45 86.81 21.22 77.16 106.10 131.18 50.15]
[27.08 84.65 79.57 38.93 79.57 0 42.32 143.90 57.56 118.51 77.87 38.93 67.72 67.72 88.03 67.72 126.97 64.33]
[19.97 88.99 67.19 25.42 58.11 45.40 0 112.60 30.87 101.70 94.44 9.08 36.32 54.48 50.85 45.40 94.44 21.79]
[118.02 121.49 64.22 109.34 123.23 147.53 107.61 0 116.29 149.27 142.32 109.34 79.84 137.12 60.74 86.78 27.77 93.72]
[42.04 106.72 61.44 48.51 22.63 54.98 27.49 108.34 0 64.68 109.96 35.57 54.98 24.25 53.36 67.91 85.70 24.25]
[107.82 178.57 116.24 117.92 42.11 117.92 94.34 144.88 67.38 0 181.94 104.45 117.92 50.54 104.45 134.77 144.88 84.23]
[75.72 22.37 87.77 67.12 142.85 79.17 89.49 141.13 117.03 185.87 0 79.17 79.17 137.68 104.98 60.23 115.31 103.26]
[11.91 74.91 44.26 13.62 61.29 39.15 8.51 107.26 37.45 105.56 78.31 0 30.64 61.29 49.37 39.15 88.53 25.53]
[69.11 67.38 13.82 29.37 77.75 69.11 34.55 79.47 58.74 120.94 77.75 32.82 0 82.93 27.64 19.00 58.74 34.55]
[63.10 134.74 88.69 71.63 18.76 68.22 51.16 134.74 25.58 51.16 136.44 61.40 81.86 0 80.16 95.51 127.92 51.16]
[56.52 85.60 17.76 50.06 64.60 83.98 45.22 56.52 53.29 100.13 98.52 46.83 25.84 75.90 0 41.99 45.22 30.68]]
[[ 0 73.12 52.71 11.90 68.02 28.90 17.00 115.63 44.21 108.83 74.82 11.90 39.11 62.91 59.51 44.21 96.92 37.41]
[73.20 0 78.31 73.20 136.20 86.82 83.42 117.47 112.36 180.46 22.13 74.91 64.69 134.49 90.23 34.05 71.50 93.63]
[81.65 85.36 24.12 55.67 105.78 111.34 70.52 48.25 89.07 144.75 105.78 70.52 37.11 116.91 31.54 57.52 24.12 64.95]
[24.76 54.48 49.53 13.20 75.95 51.18 28.06 92.46 54.48 117.22 62.74 19.81 16.51 77.60 42.92 51.18 16.51 37.97]
[77.52 155.04 110.47 85.27 0 91.09 60.08 137.60 27.13 48.45 160.86 69.77 87.21 21.31 77.52 106.59 131.79 50.39]
[32.65 102.06 95.93 46.94 95.93 0 51.03 173.50 69.40 142.88 93.89 46.94 81.64 81.64 106.14 81.64 153.09 77.56]
[19.54 87.05 65.73 24.87 56.85 44.41 0 110.15 30.20 99.49 92.38 8.88 35.53 53.30 49.74 44.41 92.38 21.32]
[127.18 130.92 69.20 117.83 132.79 158.98 115.96 0 125.31 160.85 153.37 117.83 86.03 147.76 65.46 93.52 29.92 101.00]
[48.45 123.01 70.82 55.91 26.09 63.36 31.68 124.87 0 74.55 126.73 41.00 63.36 27.95 61.50 78.27 98.78 27.95]
[111.91 185.36 120.66 122.40 43.71 122.40 97.92 150.38 69.94 0 188.85 108.41 122.40 52.46 108.41 139.89 150.38 87.43]
[81.65 24.12 94.64 72.37 154.03 85.36 96.50 152.17 126.19 200.42 0 85.36 85.36 148.46 113.20 64.95 124.33 111.34]
[12.44 78.21 46.21 14.22 63.99 40.88 8.88 111.98 39.10 110.21 81.76 0 31.99 63.99 51.55 40.88 92.43 26.66]
[58.96 57.48 11.79 25.05 66.33 58.96 29.48 67.80 50.11 103.18 66.33 28.00 0 70.75 23.58 16.21 50.11 29.48]
[60.11 128.35 84.48 68.23 17.87 64.98 48.74 128.35 24.37 48.74 129.97 58.48 77.98 0 76.36 90.98 121.85 48.74]
[60.97 92.32 19.16 54.00 69.68 90.58 48.77 60.97 57.48 108.00 106.26 50.51 27.87 81.87 0 45.29 48.77 33.09]]
[[ 0 72.82 52.50 11.85 67.74 28.79 16.93 115.17 44.03 108.39 74.52 11.85 38.95 62.66 59.27 44.03 96.54 37.26]
[69.04 0 73.86 69.04 128.46 81.89 78.68 110.80 105.98 170.21 20.87 70.65 61.02 126.85 85.10 32.11 67.44 88.31]
[74.54 77.92 22.02 50.82 96.56 101.64 64.37 44.04 81.31 132.13 96.56 64.37 33.88 106.72 28.79 52.51 22.02 59.29]
[28.74 63.22 57.48 15.32 88.13 59.39 32.57 107.29 63.22 136.03 72.80 22.99 19.16 90.05 49.81 59.39 19.16 44.06]
[65.66 131.33 93.57 72.23 0 77.15 50.89 116.56 22.98 41.04 136.26 59.10 73.87 18.05 65.66 90.29 111.63 42.68]
[31.07 97.12 91.29 44.67 91.29 0 48.56 165.10 66.04 135.96 89.35 44.67 77.69 77.69 101.00 77.69 145.68 73.81]
[20.58 91.67 69.22 26.19 59.87 46.77 0 116.00 31.80 104.77 97.29 9.35 37.42 56.13 52.38 46.77 97.29 22.45]
[121.40 124.97 66.05 112.48 126.76 151.75 110.69 0 119.62 153.54 146.40 112.48 82.12 141.04 62.48 89.27 28.56 96.41]
[55.75 141.52 81.48 64.32 30.02 72.90 36.45 143.66 0 85.77 145.81 47.17 72.90 32.16 70.76 90.06 113.64 32.16]
[106.08 175.70 114.37 116.03 41.44 116.03 92.82 142.55 66.30 0 179.02 102.77 116.03 49.72 102.77 132.60 142.55 82.88]
[74.81 22.10 86.72 66.31 141.13 78.21 88.42 139.43 115.62 183.64 0 78.21 78.21 136.03 103.72 59.51 113.92 102.02]
[13.58 85.41 50.47 15.53 69.88 44.64 9.70 122.30 42.70 120.36 89.29 0 34.94 69.88 56.29 44.64 100.94 29.11]
[72.36 70.55 14.47 30.75 81.40 72.36 36.18 83.21 61.50 126.63 81.40 34.37 0 86.83 28.94 19.90 61.50 36.18]
[72.66 155.15 102.12 82.48 21.60 78.56 58.92 155.15 29.46 58.92 157.12 70.70 94.27 0 92.30 109.98 147.30 58.92]
[62.62 94.83 19.68 55.47 71.57 93.04 50.10 62.62 59.05 110.94 109.15 51.89 28.63 84.10 0 46.52 50.10 33.99]]];

MinRateFlowW=
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]];

MinRateFlowD=
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]];

//Coefficient
 CoefcapW= 
 [[01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01]];
 CoefcapD= 
 [[01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]
 [01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01]];
 
//float RateOfAvail[Resource][Plant];
RateOfAvail=
[[120 105 0]
[105 105 165]
[105 120 120]
[150 0 120]
[105 0 0]
[105 0 0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that CPLEX reports that there is no solution, i.e. the problem as stated is infeasible, the issue may be in your model or in your data. The approaches below are very general and will usually work for most issues like this.

Start with some really simple data, such as just one product, one plant, one customer etc and with low costs and large capacities so that you **really** know it has a valid solution, and check that works. If that looks OK, try growing your problem incrementally (e.g. try adding a second product, then try a second customer, etc) and keep re-solving at each step to see where it stops working.

If that still fails, try saving your model as e.g. an LP file and look at it by eye to check that it really implements the constraints that you expect. If that looks OK, try using the built-in conflict refiner to find some sets of constraints that are infeasible with your data. You may find that it helps to name your constraints to make your LP file easier to read, but do be aware that OPL will automatically allow named constraints to be relaxed which can give misleading results (this is a pet hate of mine!).

You can also try adding constraints to force the values of some (or even all) variables to values that you know are a valid solution, and then see which sets of constraints can be shown to be incompatible.

This is just software. Keep using the old traditional techniques of breaking down the big problem into smaller parts and check each of those are working as you expect, and then build it back up until it fails, find the issue and fix it and then repeat the process. It always works eventually.